# Odd error Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Tags: android

Odd error Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

As I convert all the 'compile' into 'implementation'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yts.mnf.torrent"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')
 //   implementation files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.5.7.jar')
    // Mandatory
    // Mandatory

    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.dimorinny:floating-text-button:0.0.4'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.developer-shivam:crescento:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.ruslankishai:unmaterialtabs:0.1a'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: what's your google service plugin version

Comment: If I remember well it is because of gradle version in project `build.gradle` file. Search for `classpath` under `dependencies{}`

Comment: You might be using an old version of Realm, too

Answer (score 1):

It means at least one of your libraries is currently using the `compile` syntax in its `build.gradle`. There's nothing you can do about this except open an issue with the relevent projects, if they exist. If you're using abandoned projects, then you'll need to fork them and implement your own version (Jitpack is a service that allows you to implement any Gradle project on Github).

Also, for Gson, you can and should be using the normal implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

There's no need for the JAR.

---

Here's a list of libraries you have that are using `compile`:

- com.github.coyarzun89:fabtransitionactivity
- com.github.clans:fab
- com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library
- com.github.developer-shivam:crescento
- com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView
- com.github.Cutta:TagView
- com.ruslankishai:unmaterialtabs (this one is completely deprecated)

Many of your other dependencies are also pretty outdated. If a dependency is highlighted in yellow, click it, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and select the suggested fix to update the dependency version.

This is especially important for any Firebase or Google implementations!

Answer (score 1):

you just have to update your class path of realm in the build.gradle of application level 
to the latest version of the realm which is available [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) and your warning will be solved